# How to stitch a photo and an audio file in phonegap

Tags: java, android, cordova

I am using phonegap to create an android application.

Is it possible to stitch a picture and a sound (audio) file together using phonegap framework. The new file after stitching would be a video file.

For example, an app like animoto (for iphone). Where you choose a sound track and a few pics from the phone album and the app creates a very nice slide show with the sound being played in the background.

Can you please provide some links that would explain how to do it as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Stitching is not possible but you can concurrently run both picture and sound